# Knex cannot connect to LocalDB instance using named pipe

Tags: sql-server, database, knex.js, named-pipes

I'm attempting to connect to a LocalDB instance through Knex using a named pipe:
`np:\\.\pipe\LOCALDB#DBFBFA07\tsql\query`

I can connect to it perfectly fine through SSMS & sqlcmd, but whenever I set my Knex `config.server` property to the named pipe, it says `Failed to connect to: np:\\...\query - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND np:\\...\query`

The dev config that I'm using:

```
development: {
      client: "mssql",
      connection: {
          database: process.env.SQLSERVER_DB,
          user: process.env.SQLSERVER_USER,
          password: process.env.SQLSERVER_PASSWORD,
          server: process.env.SQLSERVER_SERVER
      }
  }
```

and my `.env` config:

```
SQLSERVER_DB=<db_name>
SQLSERVER_USER=<username>
SQLSERVER_PASSWORD=<password>
SQLSERVER_SERVER="np:\\.\pipe\LOCALDB#DBFBFA07\tsql\query"
```

Comment: The pipe name used by the instance will cycle every time LocalDB starts (and the shutdown is automatic), so this is not a reliable way to connect, even if you did get it to work. If the DB library does not explicitly support LocalDB (through the `(localdb)\<instance>` syntax), you're probably better off using SQL Server Express or a Docker instance of SQL Server rather than trying to hack your way around it.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I would use the instance name but I'm unable to connect using it through any method. I'm aware the pipe name will change every time, but that's not the main issue for me now. I'm just confused as to why I can connect via the pipe name from SSMS and sqlcmd, but not through this library. Seems odd.

Comment: Knex layers on top of the Node `mssql` driver which, as far as I'm aware, doesn't support named pipes. Instead of LocalDB have you tried using SQL Express and [enabling the TCP/IP server protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-a-server-to-listen-on-a-specific-tcp-port) for it? (Which is something you can't do for LocalDB.)

Comment: Even if it supports named pipes (which is a big if) it's undoubtedly not geared towards connecting to LocalDB, so it may well be stumbling over something as silly as using `.` for the pipe host (hence the `getaddrinfo` problem). You can try using `localhost` there, but this may cause it to treat the pipe as a network pipe, which will still not work as the LocalDB pipe is strictly local. That's under the "hacking your way around it" column. That SSMS and `sqlcmd` can connect should not be surprising; both of these are from MS itself, and of course they understand LocalDB.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Yeah I just checked [here](https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious/issues/348) and it appears the driver doesn't support LocalDB at all since it is a slimmed down implementation of the TDS protocol. My bad just assuming it did in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying `mssql` driver and TDS protocol implementation does not support named pipe connections to LocalDB. See [this](https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious/issues/348)